# WSProxy to retrieve TriggeredSendSummary report

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

We are creating TriggerSend Dashboard Report in Cloud pages. We are able to process it using AMPscript and SOAP API call, but unable to process AMPscript SOAP API response. We have decided to use WSproxy but it's displaying a blank page once published. Are we missing something here?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var cols = ["Sent","CustomerKey","NotSentDueToOptOut","NotSentDueToUndeliverable","Bounces","Opens","Clicks","UniqueOpens","UniqueClicks","OptOuts","SurveyResponses","Conversions","UniqueConversions","InProcess","NotSentDueToError"];

var filter = {
      Property: "CustomerKey",
      SimpleOperator: "equals",
      Value: "TriggersendCustomerkey"
  };

  var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendSummary", cols, filter);

Write(res.Results.Sent);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to convert the object to a string. Replace `Write(res.Results.Sent);` with `Write(Stringify(res.Results));` to display the Results array.

However, I see you would like to specifically retrieve the `Sent` value in `Results`. Note that `Results` returns an array of objects, so you would need to loop through each one and output the Sent value. The following code will do that:

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var cols = ["Sent","CustomerKey","NotSentDueToOptOut","NotSentDueToUndeliverable","Bounces","Opens","Clicks","UniqueOpens","UniqueClicks","OptOuts","SurveyResponses","Conversions","UniqueConversions","InProcess","NotSentDueToError"];

var filter = {
      Property: "CustomerKey",
      SimpleOperator: "equals",
      Value: "TriggersendCustomerkey"
  };

var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendSummary", cols, filter);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < res.length-1; i++) {
  Write('\n\nSent: ' + Stringify(res.Results[i].Sent));
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @EliotHarper, I got the answer. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @Ranjan, no problem. If this works for you (which it should, as I've tested it myself), then please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for the benefit of others.

Comment: @ranjan, please can you accept my answer?